# How to improve performance..?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function removeTds() {
    var elements = $('#goldBarList tr:not(:eq(0))').filter(':has(:checkbox:checked):lt(50)');
    var count = elements.length;
    elements.each(function() {
        grossWeightTotal = grossWeightTotal - $('#goldBarList tr:eq(' + $(this).index() + ') td:eq(8)').text();
        netWeightTotal = netWeightTotal - $('#goldBarList tr:eq(' + $(this).index() + ') td:eq(9)').text();
        fineOunceTotal = fineOunceTotal - $('#goldBarList tr:eq(' + $(this).index() + ') td:eq(10)').text();
    });
    elements.remove();
    if(count === 50) window.setTimeout(removeTds, 1);
}
removeTds();
```

The above code results in the "stop running this script?" prompt. I have 4000 records.

Answer (score 8):

Your code is inherently slow and optimizable (cache `$(this).index()` for example) but the biggest problem is that you ask the browser to run the function every 1 ms if you have 50*N records (for example 4000...).

Simply clean all in one go.

For example :

```
function removeTds() {
    var elements = $('#goldBarList tr:not(:eq(0))').filter(':has(:checkbox:checked)');
    elements.each(function() {
        var index = $(this).index();
        grossWeightTotal = grossWeightTotal - $('#goldBarList tr:eq(' + index + ') td:eq(8)').text();
        netWeightTotal = netWeightTotal - $('#goldBarList tr:eq(' + index + ') td:eq(9)').text();
        fineOunceTotal = fineOunceTotal - $('#goldBarList tr:eq(' + index + ') td:eq(10)').text();
    });
    elements.remove();
}
removeTds();
```

If you want to have the clean been remade when checkbox are changed, add this :

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(removeTds);
```

Of course you may also bind to a button :

```
$('#removeButton').change(removeTds);
```

Comment: Actually thing is when a user clicks on remove button i have to remove all the rows which have checked checkbox and i need to minus the totals... at max i can have 4000 rows..